# .NET Assemblies and Version Element Order - Looking for trouble using major.minor.revision.build

Tags: .net, version

Am I looking for trouble if I don't follow the Microsoft version order?  .NET uses **major.minor.build.revision** and my exiting C++ use **major.minor.revision.build** (although we refer to "revision" as patch).

I want one approach between the two sides of my build and I want to avoid fallout from changing my C++ version strategy.   I'd rather use major.minor.revision.build .NET but I'm concerned that this will lead to problems with how .NET finds and loads assemblies especially in patch/partial upgrade situations.

Does anyone know what the impact would be of changing the order?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how it's structured you may get compiler warnings that it's not the recommended format; however you shouldn't have any issues if you're just using them in that order.  As long as you're consistent and this is well documented, then you should be safe.  I say well documented so that anyone else that maintains your code will not make a mistake.  Again consistency is key.